# EOG artifacts turn up in several ICA source signals

Tags: eeg, ica

I try to remove EOG artifacts from my EEG signals (I am using a [EPOC+](https://www.emotiv.com/epoc/) for recording and [MNE Python](http://martinos.org/mne) for processing).

Therefore I've recorded test data with blinks every 5 seconds. The blinks can be seen clearly in the EEG data. The data have been recorded with 128Hz, bandpass filtered (1-30Hz) and resampled (64Hz).

[image: Raw EEG data]

After running the ICA ('fastica') the blinks clearly show up in 3 source signals (IC #0, #1 and #2). I have the same behavior for different amounts of ICs.

[image]

[image: ICA topo map]

I think the blinks are to strong and that's why they spread in more than one source signal.

*I wonder if there is a way to let the blinks only show up in 1 source signal?*

Comment: This look like you could further low-pass filter this and then apply a threshold to the absolute value? (I have no idea about EEG, though)

Comment: What would be the effect of further low-pass filtering?

Comment: I'd assume it'd practically eradicate all the fast, small-amplitude noise, and your peaks would still stand out, though being rounder, and you might be able to find a threshold between these and your "normal" signal. By the way, adding a fairly low-cutoff-frequency high-pass might also help with removing any bias, but I'd do that in a second step.

Comment: @MarcusMüller As I am interested in the frequency range from 1-30Hz, I cannot cut off more frequencies to remove noise.

Comment: You'd still keep the unfiltered data and use the filtered only for detecting the position of blinks. But then again, I'm really no expert in EEG

Comment: @MarcusMüller Problem is, I need the ICA source channel with the EOG artifact to remove it from the original signal (artifact correction), therefore I null the source channel with the EOG and do a backprojection.

Comment: I must admit I practically understood nothing of your last comment, sorry :D

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh, sorry, I'll try again :) My task is not only to detect the blinks. I also want to remove the blinks from the EEG signal, therefore I have to detect the source channels with blinks. The detected source channels can be removed from the original eeg signals. So I have to apply the ICA to the original eeg signals and cannot use  another (filtered) dataset. Is this understandable?

Comment: I don't fully understand why you can't detect the blinks from a filtered data set? It's still the same data, you can calculate the time the blinks happened from the detection, and selectively remove sudden peaks around that time from the original signals afterwards?

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is not what I want to do. The ICA separates the EEG signals into separate "source channels". If I can determine such a source channel to be mostly an EOG signal, I can fully leave it out for the backprojection. See this article, maybe it clear my point a bit: http://pressrelease.brainproducts.com/independent-component-analysis-demystified/ or http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/example/use_independent_component_analysis_ica_to_remove_eog_artifacts